# How to use OpenGL Column_Major MVP Matrix in Direct3D 11

Tags: c++, opengl, direct3d

I am trying to use a single matrix stack for both OpenGL and Direct3D APIs. From all my research on this site and other articles at:
[Article 1](http://seanmiddleditch.com/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/),
[Article 2](https://anteru.net/2011/12/27/1830/comment-page-1/#comment-338839) among others, it is my understanding that this should be fairly easy as long as certain nuances are handled and consistency is maintained.

Also, this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634(v=vs.85).aspx#Matrix) suggests that HLSL by default uses column_major format.

So I have a working Right-Handed Coordinate System, Column_Major MVP matrix for opengl.

I am trying to use this same matrix in DirectX. Since it is a Right-Handed System, I made sure that I do set `rasterizerDesc.FrontCounterClockwise  = true;`

I have the following in my HLSL shader :

```
output.position = mul(u_mvpMatrix, input.position);
```

Note that in the above code I am using a post-multiplication as my mvp-matrix is column major and I send it to the shader without transposing it. So it should send it as column major and therefore, the post-multiplication.

Note: I did try pre-multiplication as well as post and pre-multiplication with the transpose of my mvp.

When calculating the projection matrix, as suggested in Article 2 above, I make sure that the depth range for DX is 0-1 and for openGl it is -1-to-1!

I even tested my resulting matrix against the `XMMatrixPerspectiveFovRH` function from the DirectXMath library and my matrix matches the one produced by that function.

Now with Rasterization flag set ->`FrontCounterClockwise    = true`, RH column major MVP matrix, with correct depth scaling, I would have expected that this would be all that would be needed to get D3D to work with my Matrix.

What is it that I am missing here?

P.S: I believe I provided all the information here, but please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: You need to double-check your assumptions are correct at each intermediate step. The trouble with handedness is that as long as you have an even number if mistakes, things will appear correct. Trial and error will just get you to the nearest even number, but you'll have trouble down the road when you only need *some* of the transforms (e.g. determining world-space normals).